# Is closing as a duplicate being 'horrible'?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, etiquette

I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29605303/2675154), which was suggesting that the OP is:

- new to the site.
- new to [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css).

The OP was asking if the `float` property was interfering with their selection.

It was observed in the question that the negative `z-index` value was the cause of this. This could (reasonably) be closed as a duplicate of [Unable to click textbox with negative z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338857/cant-click-textbox-z-index-issue-im-stuck).

However, a relatively high-ranking user wrote as an answer:

> Probably a duplicate of: cant click textbox. z-index issue? im stuck
>
> If you set a negative z-index on a textbox, then you can not click
>   into it. You should try just removing that property. It likely serves
>   no purpose in your case.

then justified by saying:

> *... since the OP was new to SO, I was being nice and not immediately*
>   *voting to closing the question*

which suggests that that voting to close is being 'nasty' and not actually 'nice' for new users.

However, it does actually answer the question by saying it is the z-index. Should it be removed? What should I be doing with this sort of answer that points out a possible dupe but also answers the question?

Comment: I agree with your comment; the point of identifying duplicates is to get the OP (and all future users who end up at that question) to the best answers. Far from being horrible, it's a good way to quickly help people without duplicating content all over the site. If it's **not** a duplicate, the OP should edit the question to clarify how theirs differs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I do suppose though that this **possible duplicate of x** does sound pretty harsh, especially when new users don't know that's automatically generated...

Comment: What I tend to do is flag as duplicate, and then edit the auto-generated comment to be less harsh ("Your question may already have an answer here: [link]" or similar)

Comment: I do recall someone asking recently if the auto-comment could be altered to something softer. I don't personally see it as harsh.

Comment: I don't go to meta often, only when I get a little confused over this sort of thing. So this question, may, in fact, have similar questions.

Comment: Here it is: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288057/3001761; it didn't prove terribly popular

Comment: Glancing at the pseudo-suggested duplicate, there's nothing left in the question (originally an off site example that is no longer available). It would be an excellent opportunity to make this question (which has code in it) into the better one with better answers.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Well, evaluating both the presentation and the question aside from presentation came to the same result for me, and I think most who were there. Not saying they don't strongy re-inforce each other there. And not closing when appropriate is always wrong, even if used as an excuse to post an answer.

Comment: @MichaelT perhaps, but CodingWithSpike's answer certainly isn't a good one!

Comment: @jonrsharpe there are currently no good answers in the new one. But the old one, once you take out the intro, remove the dead link, remove the references to non-existent code, remove the appeal to poke around in the non-existent code base, and remove 'thanks' [really doesn't have much left](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7670222). There's got to be a better question out there with better answers.

Comment: @jbutler483 I applaud your answer on there. This might be one of those situations where it is appropriate to put code into the asker's question as a demonstration of the described problem.  That would make the question and answer combination there *much* better.

Comment: @MichaelT: I wouldn't advise that (since that's making up a question to suit the answer). But maybe a mod could merge or something to fix that.

Comment: @jbutler483 it is writing demonstration code that matches the problem description. The question exists. The answers to it exist (and one is even accepted). Presenting demonstration code for the problem can help future people finding the question identify if the (rather nebulous current question) matches the problem they have. Otherwise, the question is *very* poor and would serve as a ***very*** bad example for other users to ask similarly worded questions. In order for there to be a good answer, there needs to be a good question.

Comment: @MichaelT: I would agree, at present the question needs work. However, I think at this point (with the question being nearly 4 years old at this point), a mod or the OP would/should agree with this. With the OP not having been online since September Last year, I think it's up to the mods how this should be handled (merging, altering, or deleting).

Comment: @jbutler483 mods have repeatedly taken the stance that they don't do work as technical editors - it is very unlikely they will alter it. As it is a duplicate target, the mods can't delete it unless the original duplicate is cleared first. Merging comes with similar difficulties of the first two it can't be deleted and the merge target would need to be sufficiently identical for the merge to move the current answers into a new target (if you have suggestions). The path of least resistance is likely for a member of the community to make a good question there as it already has a good answer.

Comment: I have faith in the mods. whilst they may be extremely busy, I believe they'll get round to it.

Comment: Most / all things we do should be content-focussed, no user-focussed (with the exception of commenting) - user-focus is for moderators, so how new the user is should have no effect on you voting to close, editing, flagging, etc. (but feel free to let it have an effect on whether you post a comment and what you say, but if there's **a need** to do this for new users, it seems like a broken system). If people treat content significantly differently based on the user posting it, we'll have a hard time enforcing quality standards.

Comment: Is this a professional Q&A site, or a kindergarten? A dupe is a dupe, regardless of how new the user is - the search facility is available to all.

Comment: You could always delete the... "rude?" auto comment and make up your own. I don't see it as being rude at all though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the same answer imply that the questions should be closed as duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Is the same (basic) question answered elsewhere?** If yes, vote to close it. Point the user to *an existing answer* so that they can benefit from it. *That's* how you can be nice to the user — without cluttering up the site with repeated answers.

**Are you unsure if it's the same (basic) question?** If yes, vote to close it *anyway*. The comment that is created starts off by saying "possible duplicate of". Somebody will point it out if it's not a duplicate. You can then retract your vote (or vote to reopen if your vote was binding) if you deem fit.

**Is the other question topically related to your answer, but you're sure that the question you're answering is not a complete duplicate?** There are many ways to describe a related question without using the word "duplicate" (as doing so tends to prompt knee-jerk reactions from others). Even calling it a "related" question is one of them.

Technical assessment aside, that answer probably wouldn't have attracted nearly as many downvotes had it not included the duplicate link to start with. At the very least, it suggests an answer of its own that attempts to address the question. That is far better than an answer that:

- simply says "your question is answered here: [link]".
- links to the duplicate question and quotes an answer from said duplicate question.
- *plagiarizes* an answer from the duplicate question without even so much as linking to it.

The latter two kinds of answers actively harm the site by creating unnecessary copies of existing answers.

Comment: So the question now is; *what should we do with the 'original' question?* With most of the original content now void (and hence removed), it doesn't really stand on its own. Should *a member of the community to make a good question there as it already has a good answer* as MichaelT suggested?

Comment: @jbutler483: So I finally opened the duplicate link and whoa nelly that is a terribl(y localized) question - I don't even see how that user concluded that it was a suitable duplicate. The answer is obsolete - but then so is the question. It should be closed and removed entirely as it already has an accepted answer tailored to the OP's needs at the time. Your answer is much better served by its own question.

Comment: So should I look to placing this/finding a better place for this answer (although a quick glance at the serach results for 'z-index issue' brings up a *lot* of results :S)?

Comment: @jbutler483: Yeah - that old linkrot question needs to just go away.

Comment: and a nice z-index question needs to appear :L The [most suitable question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110286/why-does-negative-z-index-and-non-static-position-disable-my-checkbox-in-most-br) still doens't quite suit. But even if I did find one, I didn't think I could remove an upvoted answer anyway?.

Comment: @jbutler483: You can remove an upvoted answer - you just lose the reputation that you gained from it. Funnily enough I upvoted the answer to that question. If you can't find a suitable duplicate (and I don't blame you), feel free to draft up a new one. Hit me up on chat if you'd like a review.

Comment: @BoltClock would it be better to unclose the newer (not awful) question that has been closed as a duplicate of the old one and present a good answer there? At that point, the old question is no longer a duplicate target and could be deleted. This avoids drafting up a new question.

Comment: @MichaelT: It should be sorted now. :)

Comment: I am not sure about your suggestion to vote to close anyway: if this comes from a quoted user this can usually cause a chain reaction, difficult to revert. I point you to an example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252192/how-should-i-behave-when-i-see-a-feature-request-i-consider-unnecessary-useless Maybe in that case it's better to manually write the "Possible duplicate of" message.