# Too quick to close duplicate-seeming questions for first-timers!

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, downvotes

I'm new here, and apologize for any errors in understanding how the site works.

In my time here so far, I have noticed a pattern regarding questions being closed as duplicate:

- if the poster is new, the question is closed in a flash, even when there are nuances or clear differences between the new asker's question and the one indicated in the flag. (In the [latest instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874093/loading-sequential-web-pages-in-a-browser) the closer/flagger linked to his own answer on a related-but-by-no-means-duplicate answer.) There is no opportunity for a better question, or a more tailored/modern answer to emerge.
- if the poster is established, the question can be exactly the same as an existing one, but by the time you get around to flagging it, it already has 5 responses and an accepted answer.

I think the latter is real duplication (the kind that screws up search engine results etc), while the former takes away from the experience of first-time askers. The latter are often still figuring out how to edit and comment on their quesion, and don't get the chance to improve their question, specify how their question might be different or why another question marked as duplicate-of is not the right one.

Is there a possibility of letting at least an hour relapse between a newbie question being flagged as duplicate and being closed?

Comment: So let me get this right - you **want** two questions that are exactly the same to be treated differently, based on the asker's rep? Doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Comment: Don't mind the downvotes on this question, that [means something different here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).  I'm not trying to penalize you for your misunderstanding, I just don't think this is a good new feature.

Comment: It is somewhat assumed that "established posters" would do minimal research and find duplicate themselves... Not always the case - i.e. this one http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290081/is-closing-as-a-duplicate-being-horrible feels very close to what you are asking about :)...

Comment: Note that if OP edits question so it is no longer duplicate most likely it will be reopened almost immediately - reopen queue is one of a few that is usually less than 10 entries long (unlike close one for example).

Comment: Points taken, Jon, Makoto & Alexei. Thanks for the consideration and insights.

Answer (score 10):

I'll address the concern in general, then with the post you mention.

First, **if a question is a true duplicate, the sooner it's closed, the better.**  This enables *several* things:

- The user gets a quicker answer to their problem by reading the answer somewhere else, preferably with a lot more responses and detail
- Other users don't mistakenly answer the question with information that's been repeated too often (think [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1079354) and [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/1079354))
- The community doesn't have to expend a lot of energy dealing with the question beyond the duplicate close vote, and if it's already closed, no real energy has to be expended at that point to maintain the question.

Allowing the question to survive for an hour would be a really bad idea.

- The user's answer is at best delayed for an hour.
- The user's answers at worst contribute no new knowledge to what we've already repeated here, which tangles up another user's search for a similar problem.

Gut feeling is that the new user [didn't take the advice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) given to them when they asked a new question: they need to **research before asking**. If they do that, then they can avoid scenarios in which a question that they thought was unique was closed as a duplicate within mere *seconds* of it being posted.

As for the post you provide:  this is one of those weird cases in where I don't *like* using a dupe vote, but I could see its rationale.  The two questions are fundamentally asking the same thing, but the new question doesn't explicitly deal with Greasemonkey.

If the new question would be revised in a way that Greasemonkey is explicitly not requested, then  I could see that being reopened.