# Is there a way to accept an answer from another question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, link-only-answers

I asked a question concerning git here

[Why are my local changes not being removed by git reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708055/why-are-my-local-changes-not-being-removed-by-git-reset/39727629#39727629)

After some back and forth with other users, and a few hours banging away at my computer, I discovered that the issue was the exact same as posted in

[Git status shows file twice but different case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474218/git-status-shows-file-twice-but-different-case)

I believe that my questions should still stay, as I discovered it from observing the symptoms, while the other poster found the issue from seeing the file name difference directly. However, my accepted answer is really just https://stackoverflow.com/a/14017052/2012870.

I included and linked to that answer on my question, but is there a better way to credit the user who actually answered my question?

Comment: Its more that your question should be closed as a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: I think that closing the question as a duplicate is jumping the gun. By reading both questions you can see that I and @GraydonSvendson
had different questions, even if the answer was the same

Comment: For what it's worth, you would be right it is jumping the gun if what you say is true. [Does the same answer imply that the questions should be closed as duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate)

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes I did, thank you for catching that typo

Comment: If closed as dupe, your question becomes a signpost to the other question.  So people who have your problem go to that other question and *wow!* there's the answer to my problem!  Yay!

Comment: Meh, through the solution is the same the underlying reason is different. The other question didn't have a Windows system involved that caused the problems you observed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should vote/flag your question for closure as a duplicate if you realize it's answered by another question's answer(s), rather than posting a new answer to indicate that another answer answers your question.

Comment: The answer to the problem is a duplicate, but the observed behavior that led to the question is different. I think there's value in leaving the question so that someone who found the issue the way I did, can easily found an answer.

Comment: @AlexanderBurke I didn't tell you to delete your question, I said you should mark it as a duplicate.  If I had suggested you delete it (you actually can't delete that question anyway, even if you wanted to) then that would be a valid criticism.

Comment: @AlexanderBurke Closing your question as a duplicate won't destroy it. If anything, it will create a clearer path from it to the other question where your answer was found.

Comment: @Don'tPanic,@Servy, ah that might be what I was missing then.

Comment: @AlexanderBurke [A certain amount of duplication is good](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).  In this case, your question is likely a _useful_ duplicate to help others find the solution.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, thank you for the link. And it appears I misunderstood what a question marked as a duplicate meant

Comment: @AlexanderBurke: To clarify: this situation is pretty much exactly what duplicates are meant for, you have multiple differently phrased questions but the same answer. Using the StackExchange duplicates system, all the questions stay around, and are thus searchable and googleable, but all except one are closed with a redirection towards the canonical version, so that answers are concentrated in one place.

Comment: @AlexanderBurke no, this is not what duplicates are for. Duplicates are for questions that have the same underlying problem, show the same symptoms and the same sets of possible answers.]

Comment: @Braiam is there documentation for this? Everyone else is telling me that if its the same problem and answer, but not symptoms. I have no experience to say either way

Comment: @AlexanderBurke read http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/213575