# Is my Question not a Duplicate of Another?

Tags: discussion

Firstly, I apologize for how long this question is. I am still a fairly inexperienced member, and I've run into a very odd situation which makes me somewhat confused about what the best actions would be.

I've tried to write this question so anyone can understand it whether they know about the library and language involved. These are JavaFX and Java, respectively.

Essentially, I wrote a duplicate question despite knowing it was probably a duplicate, purely because the other "non-duplicate" question didn't have an answer that I could use.

This is because I don't know how to use the other answers since they utilized aspects of the library that are not part of the language itself, and that I didn't know. These being the library's particular versions of CSS and XML. The only answer that didn't involve those was, in my opinion, incomplete.

I feel it was incomplete because it doesn't produce the requested behavior without additional code.

I actually figured out how to solve my own problem shortly after I posted my question, and I posted an answer to it.

Of course, the person who posted that answer flagged my post as a duplicate. I also flagged my own post, because I thought that's what it was.

Then, I noticed the original question seems not to have the greatest English, so I thought I might earn some points by editing it, and writing my own answer to the question. As mentioned, I feel my own solution was more complete.

I wrote my answer to the original question, but when I started editing the original question, I became unsure the questions *were* actually duplicates.   This is because the asker says, "I know that gridLinesVisible() is for debug purposes only, so i let this beside."

I *think* what he is saying is "I know the method `setGridLinesVisible()` is for debugging purposes only, and so I don't want to use it."

gridLinesVisible() is not an actual method used by the library being asked about, so I changed the name. The method I think he's talking about is used to display the grid lines of a grid that a certain type of object creates. If he is asking about a way to show these grid lines without using `setGridLinesVisible()` then it seems like my question *might* not be a duplicate after all.This is because I basically just asked "How do I show grid lines?".

The incomplete answer I mentioned actually says that, `setGridLinesVisible()` is for debugging purposes only. Of course, if the asker wanted a non-debugging way of showing grid lines, then it's not just an incomplete answer, but possibly completely irrelevant.

The accepted answer (not the incomplete one) to the original question, also seems to understand the asker didn't want to use `setGridLinesVisible()`.

I haven't edited my question to explain why it *might* not be a duplicate, because I'm not sure what the original question is asking, and I've already flagged it as a duplicate myself.

I apologize if this is too broad of a question. I know the Help Center says, "Your questions should be reasonably scoped." But, I'm not sure how to narrow it down any more than this.

If I should do anything, what should I do now?

**My Question:**

[GridPane layout debugging lines aren't displayed as expected when calling setGridLinesVisible(true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53573893/javafx-gridpane-object-grid-lines-are-not-displayed)

**Original Question:**

[How to display GridPane object grid lines permanently, and without using the setGridLinesVisible() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619867/how-to-make-gridpanes-lines-visible/)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, the "original" question was essentially asking how to ensure that borders are drawn around all rendered cells in a `GridPane` **at all times**; yours is asking why layout borders aren't visible when you've called a **specific layout debugging method**.

That being correct, then the desired objectives are completely different and thus these questions are not duplicates in any way shape or form. It then follows that the referenced answer posted on the original question doesn't actually answer what was asked, although this is forgivable since that question wasn't phrased very well (however, the person who posted that answer was incorrect in casting a close-as-dupe vote on your question).

As such, your question and its answer should remain as-is, unclosed, and the original question and its answer should remain as-is; I would self-delete your answer to the original question, however, as although it's superior to the existing answer, neither answers fulfill what the asker (apparently) wanted. But both questions would benefit from editing (of their titles at least) to clarify the different objectives that the asker wanted to achieve - in your question's case, something along the lines of "GridPane layout debugging lines aren't displayed as expected when calling setGridLinesVisible(true)". That's a very verbose title, but it's also very descriptive and that's exactly what we want when building a library of high-quality questions and answers!

As for the close-as-dupe votes, ignore them. I don't know if mods can reverse those votes, but I don't think it really matters since, if you make the title edit I suggested, it's unlikely that future readers will feel your question is a dupe of the "original". Far more likely, I feel, is that other questions will be closed as a dupe of **yours**.

Finally, I'd like to welcome you to Stack Overflow, and thank you for posting a high-quality question. I'd like to thank you further for responding with an equally high-quality self-answer once you discovered the problem, instead of simply leaving the question to rot.  A third thanks is due for being humble enough to consider the possibility that your question is a duplicate. And I'd like to give you a fourth thanks for being willing to engage with the issue on Meta - again with a well-written and thoughtful question - when many others would have thrown their toys and denounced Stack Overflow as hostile on social media.

You are exactly the kind of mature, thoughtful and self-aware user Stack Overflow needs, and I wish you many more years of contributing constructively to our community.

Oh, and don't forget to self-accept your answer to your question once the deadline for doing so expires.

Comment: Titles are SOO overlooked, take for example this post :)

Comment: @bjones01001101 Sorry, I was kind of at a loss for what to call it.

Comment: Note that "the desired objectives are completely different" is *not* sufficient to meet *some* users' definition of "duplicate". Some users believe (and operate under the premise) that if there exists a single answer that can adequately address two questions, then **by definition** those questions are duplicates of each other. I don't subscribe to this, but you will find plenty of SO users who do.

Comment: @ John Y https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292329/8061009 supports that questions with the same answer are not necessarily duplicates.

Comment: the close votes will age away after a while if not hammered/confirmed by 5 people.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you really think your own question would duplicate some existing question that has mediocre answers, you can:

- **offer a bounty:** Nothing gets people typing like a chance to score a nice bounty.
- **comment on the best answers:** Maybe you can get the authors to improve or expand them. If the answer is unclear or incomplete, try to politely point out what you think needs to be improved.
- **comment on the question:** Sometimes the problem is that question isn't stated all that clearly. A suggested improvement could help get an answer that'll help both you and the OP.
- **write your own question:** If you write a much better version of a question and inspire some solid answers, that first question might eventually get closed as a duplicate of *your* question regardless of the temporal incongruence. It can help to include a link to the existing question and explain why the answers there aren't sufficient — in particular, that can help focus your question and make it seem less like a dupe. BTW, one of the standard comments for answers that are questions says something like: "Please don't post questions as answers; if you need further help, create a new question."