# Are we not allowed to close this question asked by a staff member?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions

An SO staff member asked an interesting question here: [Overriding :root CSS variables from inner scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58206867/8620333) which is, at least for me, a perfect duplicate of another one: [CSS scoped custom property ignored when used to calculate variable in outer scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52015737/8620333). I closed it and added my comment.

The question get reopened **almost instantly** without any comment or edit made to the question.

Is there any special treatment to such question?

Even if it's already at +12 and will get more views than the other one, the answer is already in the target and I am convinced that it's actually the only answer explaining his issue and all the possible workarounds. Even If we can imagine there will be another answer, it should still belong to the duplicate target.

<sup>I also consider the fact that I may be wrong. In all the cases, at least a comment or an edit to the question should be added.</sup>

**UPDATE**

> I do not agree it's a duplicate question, though the answer/solution may be similar the questions are quite different (e.g. one's integers and another is colors, which have different concerns and potentially alternative approaches and workarounds). I get that they are closely related in the CSS3 world, but the workarounds and suggestions for each may differ. 
>   – Nick Craver♦

Both question deal with the same issue which is the impossibility of changing the value of a CSS variable if it's already evaluated at `:root` level.

The code from Aaron question:

```
:root {
  --orange: hsl(255, 72%, var(--lightness, 68%));
}
.card {
  background: var(--orange);
}
.card:hover {
  --lightness: 45%;
}
```

The code from the duplicate

```
:root {
  --size-1: calc(1 * var(--scale, 1) * 1rem);
  --size-2: calc(2 * var(--scale, 1) * 1rem);
  --size-3: calc(3 * var(--scale, 1) * 1rem);
}

.size-1 { font-size: var(--size-1) }
.size-2 { font-size: var(--size-2) }
.size-3 { font-size: var(--size-3) }

.scale-1x { --scale: 1 }
.scale-2x { --scale: 2 }
.scale-3x { --scale: 3 }
```

In both cases, we have `var(x)` at `:root` then we try to update it. This won't work and I am explaining why considering a detailed answer using the specification and highlighting all the possible workarounds.

a quote from my answer that apply to both cases:

> In all the cases, we should avoid any evaluation at `:root` level because it's simply useless. The root level is the uppermost level in the DOM so all the elements will inherit the same value and it's impossible to have different values inside the DOM unless we evaluate the variable again.

I also commented on Aaron question after the closure:

> short answer: it's impossible. if var() is used inside :root then it's over, it's already evaluated for all the DOM

Comment: If it's bad, close it. Doesn't matter if it's a low-rep user, high-rep user, mod, staff, or any other unmentioned group.

Comment: FWIW this was posted by Nick on Twitter and retweeted by the Stack Overflow account: https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1179473861122969601 This almost certainly accounts for the score.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl I think the problem is not that it's a bad question, but that it is a duplicate of a question that already has an answer.

Comment: If it was closed and reopened, should it not have an edit history so we can see who closed and opened it?

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl The question arose because Temani mjolnir'd it but Nick reopened it. Though Nick does also have a gold badge in CSS.

Comment: @RobertColumbia dupe is bad in this context.

Comment: @halfer copy the post ID, go to `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/<id>/revisions`. It needs an edit to add a link

Comment: @halfer it does have a revision history but because it hasn't been edited yet (closures don't "count" quite) you don't see the link. See the revisions here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58206867/revisions

Comment: Well, [Nick *does* have a CSS gold badge](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58206867/timeline), which weighs more than the diamond in this scenario.  Using that determination, he likely reopened the question. Nothing untoward here; just gold badge holders doing what they think is best.

Comment: well, an explanation about why it was reopened would be welcome

Comment: @Makoto but not *instantly*. I think my answer need few minutes to read and cover his issue. At least few comments to explain why he disagree about the duplicate. I am not realy against the reopen action.

Comment: If two gold badge holders disagree with each other about a duplicate status, then a good compromise is to leave the question open, and put the potential duplicate link in the comments. In the time it takes to discuss this one - maybe an edge case? - we could close ten other questions `:-)`.

Comment: @TemaniAfif:  All I've done is remove the "staff" part and isolate it to "two SMEs in CSS disagree about dupes".  There's a lot of people out there who get agitated about how long  people bother to read through dupes before making a unilateral decision - either close OR open - so that's not really changing anything.

Comment: I just hope some other gold badge owners aren't going to re-hammer it just to annoy StackExchange employees who aren't exactly experiencing a sudden raise of popularity atm. Focus on content, not people or organizations.

Comment: Instead of re-closing it (I tend to agree it is a dupe based on my knowledge) I did ping Nick on Twitter to provide a response here if possible. cc @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You're right and I hope another close vote by a gold-badge holder isn't automatically considered an annoyance towards SE staff.

Comment: @Tom let's do nothing until everyone agrees about leaving it open or re-close it.

Comment: @Makoto it's the first time I see a Staff asking question related to SO development so I wanted to verify if there is any *special* treatement with such questions. Now it's seems not so I want an explanation about the reopen. I take all the questions I close seriously (I am at 2200+ question closed and only 74 reopened)

Comment: @TemaniAfif:  No one cares if they're staff because they're not posting an official staff announcement on the main site.  It *literally* does not matter.  If they're asking a question, then they're treated like any other OP out there.

Comment: @Makoto It sounds like you're answering the question (which isn't what comments are for).

Comment: @TylerH:  If you want to take my comments and put them into a community wiki, feel encouraged to.

Comment: @Makoto I would, but I feel Machavity has already adequately answered that question and have upvoted his answer.

Comment: Hey all - I reopened the question from a CSS (not a mod) standpoint. I do not agree it's a duplicate question, though the _answer/solution_ may be similar the questions are quite different (e.g. one's integers and another is colors, which have different concerns and potentially alternative approaches and workarounds). I get that they are closely related in the CSS3 world, but the workarounds and suggestions for each may differ. I did read answers (present at the time) before re-opening it by the way. I'm not dead set on any decision here and will respect what the community thinks collectively.

Comment: Thanks for explaining here, @NickCraver :)

Comment: @NickCraver sorry but there is no difference between an interger or colors when it comes to CSS variables and scope. My answer still apply

Comment: @TemaniAfif I respectfully disagree that duplicate _answers_ means a duplicate _question_. The latter question was asking about outer scope (and used root as an example) - here specifically Aaron is _only_ after root scope - which indeed has different inherent constraints.

Comment: @NickCraver I'm not that deep in the CSS matter, but generally speaking: a question is a dupe, when the answer(s) on another question also solve the issue in this question. There can be slight differences in the question, but they don't matter if the first premise ("other answer also answers this question") still applies. Isn't that the same here?

Comment: @NickCraver root scope is a particular case of an outer scope which means that the target I used is more generic. CSS variable works from top to bottom so the issue of evaluating a CSS variable at outer scope and trying to change it at an inner one is what the purpose of both question

Comment: @Tom I think that's a controversial topic. Some people think that only questions should be considered for dupes, others say we should be pragmatic and use answers too. I don't have time to dive into meta, but this has been discussed before.

Comment: I'm not gonna lie, [this looks an awful lot like a conflict of interests](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1179456264742588418).

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl I don't believe there is one. On the contrary; Nick knows more about the problem and he can use that to tell whether the dupe is appropriate. He's primarily not an employee; he's a subject-matter expert with 500k+ reputation on main.

Comment: Also FYI I'm still thinking about a better title to Aaron's question as it's currently not so much about overriding :root as it is about being able to declare partial variable changes in inner scopes.

Comment: Okay, I've found a relevant discussion: [Does the same answer imply that the questions should be closed as duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate). (cc. @Tom)

Comment: The things that go down when I'm not on call... (thanks @TylerH for bringing this to my attention)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Staff questions aren't any different than those of any other user. Diamond or not, your question can be closed.

Now, if you have a diamond, you can, of course, reopen your own question. That's not what happened here. This question was [reopened by Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58206867/timeline) who has a [gold badge in the CSS tag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) and can thus reopen with a single vote anyways. If there is an issue with that, I would suggest you take it up with him. As he un-hammered it, he is pingable in comments.

Comment: yes I missed the @Name in my comment on the question because I didn't pay attention to *who* reopened. I saw a diamond and I thought it was the asker.

Answer (score 52):

Explaining myself here: I reopened the question from a CSS (not a mod) standpoint (though we can't differentiate that in the UI).

I did not agree it's a duplicate question, though the *answer/solution* may be similar the questions are quite different (e.g. one's integers and another is colors, which have different concerns and potentially alternative approaches and workarounds).

I get that they are closely related in the CSS3 world, but the workarounds and suggestions for each may differ (for example this question *specifically* deals with CSS3 root calculations - which have no outer scope in themselves).

I did read answers (present at the time) before re-opening it by the way. I'm not dead set on any decision here and will respect what the community thinks collectively, and don't mind being questioned one bit :) I think these type of discussions are good.

Comment: I added an edit to my question

Comment: by the way, I am also using an example with colors in my answer to explain the issue which is very similar to the one used in Aaron question

Comment: @TemaniAfif I totally agree the answers and/or workarounds (or lack there of) may end up being duplicates - no contention there whatsoever (though I can _hope_ not). I don't agree the _questions_ are duplicates - they're scoped differently. To me (again - I'm not speaking as a mod here), an answer saying why it's the same situation and why the constraints _are_ the same and pointing to the original answer is what _I'd_ do. I can only speak for me though - really curious what the community collectively thinks here.

Comment: @NickCraver: I guess if you want answer to whether this is a duplicate or not, then you will need a new meta question. The way this one is currently framed is based on the false premise that questions of employees are treated differently. I don't think you can get a meaningful interpretation of the votes here since it's now mixed up between the employee discussion and the duplicate closing.

Comment: @BDL I wouldn't say it's based on a false premise, but rather *asking whether this is any special treatment* in the first place.

Comment: I have tried to demonstrate with my last edit that both questions are duplicate. I am not talking about my anwser. Both code uses :root and both tries to change the value later.

Comment: @NickCraver Thank you for the response, though FWIW I remain unconvinced that Aaron's question is different from the target question (as Temani is right that the variable can be anything [number or color] and both cases are about declaring a variable in :root and then trying to override it later. E.g. even though the target Q doesn't explicitly specify they're talking about :root in their question, it's the scope they use in their code (and they don't mention any lower scope than :root as an 'outer' scope. Even if they did, it'd make the target an even better target as it's broadly applicable)

Comment: I was under the impression that if the answers are the same, the questions are considered dupes, even if they don't look the same on the surface. But maybe you guys do it differently in the CSS tag?

Comment: @CrisLuengo not just 1 answer, which is the caveat to the rule of thumb, but *all possibles answers*. As Nick explained, there could be multiple mutually exclusive solutions for the issue. Are there actually? I don't know enough CSS to do that judgement.