# Should it be ok to flag as duplicate because I think the answer on another question will answer perfectly?

Tags: discussion

I have seen quite a lot of questions flagged as "duplicate" that are actually different questions that may indeed be solved the same way.

It looks like this:

- Q1: "My compiler raises issue X", answered by: "you have to update it to V5.8.57: you use feature Y and it was bugged before this patch"
- Q2: "Feature Y shows weird results": tagged as duplicate of Q1

(also: [the last case I saw, but really it is only one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68091618/why-is-pycharm-throwing-errors-when-i-try-to-import-from-inside-a-package?noredirect=1#comment120362588_68091618))

Personally I think this is terrible: maybe Q2's asker already updated their compiler. Even if it was indeed one correct answer, it doesn't leave room for Q2's asker to accept another, more correct, answer, or for anyone else to state they don't think updating the compiler is the best way to make feature Y work.

I think a better practice would be to add an answer to Q2 that links to Q1's "good answer".

---

Not the same as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258804/duplicate-question-but-only-when-you-know-the-answer), since I am talking about cases where it is not necessarily obvious whether the same answers would work: it is only assumed by the person who marked as duplicate. Advice like "It is obvious in hindsight, so any comment is superfluous." wouldn't make sense here.

Comment: It can honestly depend. What you seem to be describing is a "sign post", where the question is different, but the answer is the same. There's nothing wrong then with closing it as a dupe; if it's a good sign post it'll be upvoted and will get people to the right answer when they have the same question. Perhaps this answers your question? [Should we consider answers when closing questions as duplicates?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408244/should-we-consider-answers-when-closing-questions-as-duplicates/408268#408268)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: I would say the theme is similar, but not exactly the same. I am talking purely about question that are clearly not asking the same thing but where an answer to Q1 could actually also help solving Q2

Comment: "*different questions that may indeed be solved the same way.*" [the post notice already says "has answers"](https://i.imgur.com/dBScyq4.png), so it's the solution that's the same. It doesn't say "your question is the same as that one". "*I think a better practice would be to add an answer to Q2 that links to Q1's "good answer".*" which is *exactly* the thing duplicates are supposed to prevent - fragmenting the knowledge. No need for three answers that say "see answer here".

Comment: Worth pointing out, though: "*maybe Q2's asker already updated their compiler.*" then it sounds like updating the compiler will *not* solve the issue. Hence, it's not a duplicate in that case.

Comment: @VLAZ: Except one can't possibly know when flaging as a duplicate that this other answer will work. They can be convinced that it will be the case, but not *know* it.

Comment: @AnneAunyme if you really want to put that argument forward, then it's self-defeating. I can equally say that *you*, as a question asker whose question was closed, can also never *know* that an answer will not work. You can be convinced that is the case but not *know* it. Therefore you shouldn't argue in favour of reopening. Yet that's not quite correct, right? The standard system is that if people are convinced another question is a dupe of yours, they express that through votes. You are still able to point out if that's not the case by clarifying your question.

Comment: @VLAZ I can try what the answer suggests and see wether it works or not, unlike the one who flags. (This is why the askers can accept the answers btw, and the answerers can't simply declare their answer as "the right one")

Comment: If the solution provided in the dupe does not work, the question can be edited to add that information and reopened. Sadly, the example you chose ("_upgrade your tools_") seems like a very uninteresting question that would rarely be worth spending time on.

Comment: The acceptance of an answer means almost nothing. You shouldn't put too much significance on it. If it turns out the duplicate *does* answer the question, then feel free to upvote the answer(s) that work. If the duplicate *doesn't* answer the question, then edit to clarify why - most likely, it's not evident by reading it. See [“This question already has answers here” - but it does not. What can I do when I think my question's not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252252)

Comment: @VLAZ you are skimming around, here. My point is that the asker can check if an answer correctly answers their issue, but an answerer usually can't.

Comment: @AnneAunyme: If the asker has tried the solution in the duplicate and it didn't help, then they should edit their question and state exactly that. Then the question can be reopened.

Comment: An asker can still check if the answers in the dupe work. What is the problem?

Comment: @BDL yes, this can work, but it goes against the possibility for anyone who steps by to consider that the answer in the duplicate is not so great as an answer for Q2 (despite being great for Q1) and to post a better one.

Comment: And here we go again... you are using duplicates the exact same way that this very question asks not to be used...

Comment: Marking a question as duplicate doesn't mean it's a bad question. Sometimes it is, and the author might delete it, but sometimes, even if I mark the question as duplicate and so does the author/community, I say to the author when asking to not delete it. Why? Because he/she uses different words, other "meaning", other "cases", but in the end, same solution/reason. So I suggest to keep it for search/references, and it will lead automatically to the duplicate question. Another one would find this one, but not the original, so it's a "good" duplicate in my opinion.

Comment: Side note, the author can edit the question or comment to say which answer he/she used in case of multiple answers.