# Should I mark the workaround as the accepted answer when an actual solution doesn't exist yet?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

**Assumption:** If I recall, once you mark an answer, you can't change it unless the accepted answer is edited after the fact. If I'm mistaken and you can change the answer if/when a better one is given, this question is moot.

**Context:** On Stack Overflow, I asked [How do you create a numbered checklist (AKA task list) in GitHub flavored Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78163737/61624) Unfortunately, it's not possible to do this *at this time* because GitHub's CSS hides the numbers of the ordered list. But this Markdown content renders the correct HTML:

```
1. [ ] A
2. [ ] B
3. [ ] C
```

As a workaround, you can nest the check list within a numbered list:

```
1. - [ ] A
2. - [ ] B
3. - [ ] C
```

This doesn't render properly, but it gets the job done. I can imagine GitHub changing their CSS one day—perhaps this is a bug that'll be fixed—so that the original markdown renders as a numbered checklist.

**Question:** Since the best solution *at this time* is a workaround, should I mark it as the accepted answer or hold off until a real fix is posted as a solution?

Comment: There's no requirement that you mark something as the answer at all. If you don't feel comfortable marking it as the answer, don't. You can certainly change it later.

Comment: @KevinB I'd say the question is slightly different because I'm assuming a solution will exist in the future and they are assuming it won't. That said, the accepted answer on your link answered mine. I've observed that that usually suffices to mark a question as a duplicate, so I'll vote to close mine. Thanks for the link! Mind telling me how you found it because I tried to look before I asked.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you assume, the answer is the answer. I searched "should i accept" and scrolled a little bit.

Comment: @KevinB Hypothetically, if my question were "What's 2+2?" and another post has an answer of "4," should my question be marked as a duplicate? Doesn't it *depend* on the question of that other post? What if its question is, "How many doors does a sedan have?" Apologies if it sounds like I'm arguing. That's not my intent: I'm trying to make sense of my observations re: questions closed as duplicates.

Comment: Generally, yes. Many questions on SO are closed in that very way every day.

Comment: @KevinB Yeah, I've observed the same thing. I still don't understand it though.

Comment: @KevinB [Found a relevant question to this topic.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292372/61624) The answer with the most votes says questions shouldn't be closed as duplicates for this alone.

Comment: Fortunately, then that doesn't apply in this case. ;)

Comment: Questions are pretty much just vessels, the only thing that REALLY matters are the answers. Those are the bread and butter, a question without a valid answer won't help anyone else solve a problem. So I do understand why duplicate closure is based on answers. But what I don't understand is that the actual link is only to a question. Many questions have numerous answers and probably only one will be the actual valid answer to the duplicated question (because we also like to create list-of-things...). But in order to establish that link all you can do is post a comment noting it :/

Comment: @Gimby The point of scoping questions properly is to prevent that from mattering. Aside from that, a lot of older questions are flooded with more or less useless duplicate / subset answers. And honestly, questions are important; they're how the scope is set, and they're the first confirmation that a reader gets of being in the right place.